# Select all types of employess then specific employee

Tags: c#, linq, polymorphism

This is kind of homework so can someone guide me (instead of answering) how to combine these two LINQ queries. This is the question

> Update the PayrollSytem by using LINQ to map the List in to a list of anonymous objects in which each object contains an Employee’s name and earning. When a BasePlusCommissionEmployee is encountered, give a 10% base-salary increase without modifying the original BasePlusCommissionEmployee object. Display the names and earnings.

so far i have this

```
var model1 = employees.OfType<BasePlusCommissionEmployee>().Select(x => new
    {
        x.FirstName,
        x.LastName,
        Increased_salary=x.BaseSalary*=1.10M
    });

var model = employees.Select(x => new
    {
        x.FirstName,
        x.LastName,
        earning = x.Earnings()
    });

foreach (var item in model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

UML diagram of class is [image: UML Diagram]

So the queries seperately works fine but is there some way to make it one query. If any other code is required I'll provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check whether the employee is a base plus commission employee using a ternary operator inside the anonymous class.

```
employees.Select(x => new { 
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName,
    Salary = x is BasePlusCommissionEmployee ? (x as BasePlusCommissionEmployee).BaseSalary * 1.1M : x.Earnings()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i forgot to mention that Employee is an abstract class so Employee doesnt have BaseSalary property only Basepluscommision have BaseSalary property

Comment: Well thanks for answer it worked but i wished u would have guided me instead of answering (well no regrets). but still thanks